# Сделать импорт данных в тег select

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqldeveloper

```js
function display_docs()
{
  global $con;
  $query="select doctor_name from doctors";
  $result=oci_parse($con,$query);
  oci_execute($result);
  while($row=oci_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $doctor_name=$row['DOCTOR_NAME'];
    echo '<option value="'.$doctor_name.'">'.$doctor_name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="doctor" class="form-control" >
  <?php display_docs();?>
</select>
```

У меня имеется функция которая берет данные с базы данных Oracle, как софт использую SQL Developer, Я хочу брать данные которые хранятся в базе и пихнуть их в тег select, пробовал устранить баг через команду var_dump, но там у меня все данные выходят, а в самом сайте где они должны появится их нет. Также я вызываю эту функцию в HTML коде.

Comment: Почему бы не подставлять данные не функцией а объектом или массивом? Мне кажется так явнее.

Comment: можно пример на то что вы говорите?

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из данных, которые вы предоставили в ответах на комментарии, код вашей функции написан корректно. Значит проблема не в функции, а в том как вы её вызываете. 
В вашей функции есть указание на глобальную переменную $con, то есть до вызова вы должны её определить и поместить в глобальном контексте - проверьте, что вы выполняете подключение к БД и переменная $con определена.
Если ошибка всё ещё не ясна, то включите логирование ошибок и проверьте лог ошибок веб сервера, самый простой вариант - включить отображение ошибок в потоке вывода, вы можете это сделать прямо в вашем php-скрипте (в самом начале):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Это позволит определить проблему гораздо быстрее

Comment: можете сейчас посмотреть на вопрос я его корректировал

Comment: Я уже указал, что без var_dump ничего не понятно, если вы попробовали применить моё решение и оно не помогло, то добавьте в описание результат вывода ваше функции с var_dump($row) внутри while.

Comment: Ну так я добавил прочтите пожалуйста в самом низу стоит

Comment: Я вижу, что вы добавили нечто, но это не похоже на вывод var_dump($row).
Выполните код ниже и добавьте, пожалуйста, результат вместо того, что вы добавили:
  $result=oci_parse($con,"select doctor_name from doctors");
  oci_execute($result);
  while($row=oci_fetch_array($result)) var_dump($row);

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "Dr. Assem Talasbek" ["DOCTOR_NAME"]=> string(18) "Dr. Assem Talasbek" } array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "Dr. Bekzat Yernat" ["DOCTOR_NAME"]=> string(17) "Dr. Bekzat Yernat" } array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Atakhan" ["DOCTOR_NAME"]=> string(7) "Atakhan" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Shynggys" ["DOCTOR_NAME"]=> string(8) "Shynggys" } array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Aziz" ["DOCTOR_NAME"]=> string(4) "Aziz" } Выходит вот это